# markdown editor with file tree for ubuntu

Tags: markdown, editor

I am looking for a text editor with markdown syntax highlighting to edit my files for Hugo. There is a lot of editors, but I would need to see my document tree beside the editing field there as well so I can switch files without clicking through a menu.

I would love if the editor would be even able to help me with linking within my hugo project, so that it automatically shows autocompletions when I want to create a link to another file within my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) has great support for [markdown](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown). You can add [relative path](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakob101.RelativePath)  plug-in in for path completions.

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](https://cudatext.github.io/) is free, open source. It has the Project Manager plugin in the side panel - it will show files tree after you make the project with some root folder. It also shows code-tree in side-panel but you didn't ask it.

Markdown syntax highlight is out of the box.

Auto-completion for Markdown isn't there, you may write a plugin.